# How can I automatically sync deleted photos between my desktop and Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, synchronization, photos, mac

Now that Google has [decoupled Google Photos and Google Drive](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-photos-drive-sync-997911/), Photos no longer syncs with my desktop Mac. Whereas [before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124622/deleting-photo-from-a-desktop-folder-synced-with-drive-backup-and-sync-deletes-f), deleting an image from the web app/Finder *also* removed that image from the other library, now the collections become asymmetrical. This is supremely annoying as I had been using the Google Photos webapp to manage the photo files on my computer (it is an old iMac and iPhotos/Photos/Aperture are very slow). Is there a script or tool I can install to get back the helpful functionality Google recently took away?

Comment: It was extremely irritating that Google decoupled Google Photos from Google Drive. Basically, they want you to keep everything in Google Photos cloud. The only solution I can think of is to use Google Takeout to download all your Google Photos to your mac. Then use a directory comparison tool to compare the differences and delete accordingly. If you want to have photo backup that syncs to a desktop file system in the future, then you'll have to use a service like Amazon Photos, Dropbox, or OneDrive.